# Using Microsoft office dlls without packaging them

Tags: dll, packaging, outlook-addin

Is there a way to create and install a Microsoft Office Add-in without packaging the referred dll files. Assuming Microsoft Office is installed in the target PC where the Add-in can be installed, how to refer the Office dlls using C# code in the Add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx).

Comment: When I exclude the Office dll's how will it get the required assembly reference at the target PC? I tried excluding the dll's but it didn't work after installation.

Comment: After changing the Copy Local flag of the assembly, it worked.. thanks